# how to create an object in R function (linear regression formula)

Tags: r

Does anyone know why my function doesn't work? I know it must have sth to do with the environment.

```
myfun <- function(dat, response) {
  form <- as.formula(response ~., env = .env)
  coef(summary(glm(form, data=dat, family=binomial(logit))))
}
```

Comment: What are you passing to response? A string? A vector?

Comment: what is .env?  you want `as.formula(paste(response, "~."))`

Comment: sorry for not providing details. dat is a data frame and response is the name of one column in the data frame. For example, coef(summary(glm(death ~ ., data=df, family=binomial(logit)))) is the coefficients when you treat the death column in the data frame as the predictor variable y and all the other columns in the data frame as x.